# Postgresql: How to increase by 1 on a jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

In `Postgresql` 9.6, There is a table contains a column `data jsonb`, it has a `count` field.
How to increase `data->>count` by 1 in a single sql? Like `$inc` from mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ugly but works.  I'm just figuring this out now by readings [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html), so there may very well be a better way of doing this.

Let's start with a simple table:

```
create table table1 (data jsonb);
```

Insert some JSON:

```
insert into table1 (data) values ('{"name": "example", "count": 0}');
```

Now, we want to update the value of the `count` key in the `data` column.  Assuming that you have pg 9.5 or later, you can use the concatenation operator to merge two json (or jsonb) dictionaries, like this:

```
sandbox=# select data || '{"count": 1}' as data from table1;
              data               
---------------------------------
 {"name": "example", "count": 1}
```

So we know how to update a JSON key.  But in the above example I'm using a static value in the replacement, while we actually want "one more than the current value of count".  We can use the concatenation operating with strings to build the necessary JSON:

```
sandbox=# select '{"count": ' || ((data->>'count')::int + 1) || '}' as count from table1;
    count     
--------------
 {"count": 1}
```

Putting that together:

```
sandbox=# update table1 set data = data || ('{"count": ' || ((data->>'count')::int + 1) || '}')::jsonb ;
UPDATE 1
```

Which gets us:

```
sandbox=# select * from table1;
              data               
---------------------------------
 {"name": "example", "count": 1}
```

Comment: This works, but it replace the whole `data`, wondering is there something  in pg like `$inc` from mongodb, or is it actually the same (*replace the whole document*) in mongodb under the hood?